# Sending files over Nodejs Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, request, socket.io

I'm trying to send a mp3 file over a socket to the users browser. The mp3 file, which I'm trying to send, is downloaded using request. How do I pipe from a request to a socket and reconstruct the file at the users end?

This is my code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('download.request', function(result) {

        // Get song info
        request.get("xxx", function(error, response, body) {
            var track = JSON.parse(body);

            // Download song using info
            request.get("xxx", function(error, response, body) {
                socket.emit('download.file', body);
            });

            io.emit('download.log', {
                time: moment().calendar(),
                name: track.title,
                url: result.url
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Delivery](https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js) library?

Comment: I have but I couldn't get it to work and the guide only taught how to initiate a transfer when the initial socket connection is made...